# Best Practices for where to keep your API keys for AWS when running a Java app

Tags: java, security, amazon-web-services

I have a Java App that connects to AWS to do various things with EC2 and S3, when deploying to production I'd obviously like to keep the keys out of the codebase. Is it advisable to keep the keys as environment variables on the server or have a file located somewhere that I read in at startup and set the access key values or other?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have written similar code. Initially, I had the `pem` files and everything in app's resources folder. Soon, we realized that it's not good to have it a part of source control.

Since it's one time thing, we ended up saving the file to the server where our deployer app was installed in a folder with only `R`ead permission to the user that runs the deployer app.

So, my advice is keep in a file away from your source control, in secure place.

Comment: I would recommend to keep this file in source control. Only that files which have server specific properties should be saved on server and this doesn't seem the case here.

Comment: @SanjeevKumarDangi -- private key pair should NEVER EVER change hands. There should be only one copy and it should be specific. When you put in SCM, each dev would have a copy. Leaving the consequences of an angry ex-employee blowing your prod, there are chances of ones machine gets hacked and your key pair is shared on pastebin. Also, if many people make changes using the shared key -- it will be hard to distinguish if a task is done by the app or an user. Even OP rejects the idea of keeping this props in code base -- it's so obvious.